# How to dynamically tweak XML with MarkupBuilder?

Tags: templates, groovy

I have a XML template and I'd like to be able to add/remove/update attributes to the template dynamically, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the template and what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear from the heading and the question itself whether you are looking for dynamically modifying an XML or an XML template (they are two different entities) hence  summarized both options:

**Modifying attributes in an XML**

```
def xml = '''
<cars>
  <car type='sedan'>Honda</car>
  <car type='sedan' category='standard'>Toyota</car>
</cars>
'''

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

//Add
slurper.car.find { it.text() == 'Honda' }.@year = '2013'

//Modify
slurper.car.find { it.text() == 'Toyota' }.@type = 'Coupe'

//Delete
slurper.car.find { it.text() == 'Toyota' }.attributes().remove( 'category' )

groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( slurper )
```

**Creating an XML from a template using XmlTemplateEngine**

Excerpts taken from [XmlTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/XmlTemplateEngine.html) API:

```
def binding = [firstname:"Jochen", lastname:"Theodorou", 
               nickname:"blackdrag", salutation:"Dear"]
 def engine = new groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine()
 def text = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <document xmlns:gsp='http://groovy.codehaus.org/2005/gsp' 
           xmlns:foo='baz' type='letter'>
   <gsp:scriptlet>def greeting = "${salutation}est"</gsp:scriptlet>
   <gsp:expression>greeting</gsp:expression>
   <foo:to>$firstname "$nickname" $lastname</foo:to>
   How are you today?
 </document>
 '''
 def template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
 println template.toString()
```

**Creating XML from a template using MarkupTemplateEngine**

Since Groovy 2.3, we can also use [MarkupTemplateEngine](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0-beta-1/html/gapi/groovy/text/markup/MarkupTemplateEngine.html) to create xml in a [DSL builder](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT/html/documentation/markup-template-engine.html) style:

```
import groovy.text.markup.*
import groovy.text.Template

def xmlTemplate = '''
xmlDeclaration()
cars {
   cars.each {
       car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
   }
}
'''
class Car {
    String make, model
}
def model = [
    cars: [
        new Car(make: 'Peugeot', model: '508'), 
        new Car(make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius')
    ]
]

def render(xmlTemplate, model) {
    MarkupTemplateEngine engine = 
        new MarkupTemplateEngine(
           new TemplateConfiguration( autoNewLine: true, autoIndent: true ) )
    Template template = engine.createTemplate( xmlTemplate )
    Writable output = template.make( model )
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    output.writeTo( writer )
    println writer
}

render( xmlTemplate, model )
```

Comment: You gave me more than I want, thank you @dmahapatro.